# Wine background applications

Tags: windows, wine, background-process

You know, if you have Windows, you have in the down right corner those programs. If I start a Windows program on Ubuntu (TPFanControl), it automatically runs in background, but I cannot figure out, where that "Windows down right corner" list of apps is.

Thanks for your answers, I appreciate any help.

Sry for bad English, I'm Slovak.

Comment: Click on the Dock Ubuntu icon, then type "Startup Applications".  That's where you can manage the programs that get automatically run for your session.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for something similar to "System Monitor" and loof after the program that are running right now in your system.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cannot run Windows programs under Wine where the program interfaces with device drivers (ie. fan controller).

You should search for a native linux app that will handle this. If you are comfortable using the command line have a look at this last message in this thread https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/controlling-fan-speed-either-automatically-on-debian-7-1-amd64-wheezy-4175477335/